# Using Active Storage saving images in local storage with Docker will sometimes perform 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rails-api, rails-activestorage

I am developing a React App using RailsAPI as the backend and using Docker with nginx-proxy to deploy to the server. One of the function is to allow user to upload images to server and show it again in the frontend. I am trying to use Active Storage to manage those files and saving them in local storage. However, it is strange that, sometimes the images were broken in some browser, but they were able to be shown when using another browser or even just incognito mode within the same device. I have searched for awhile already but still with no luck. Switching the storage location to external storage will be the last resort as it was just a very minor function of my project.

**To make long story short**, **read the following summary of my practice.**

I am using Docker with containers - 1) nginx-proxy, 2) railsapi, 3) react

Inside RailsAPI, am using ActiveStorage storing images in local storage.

With the same image url generate from RailsAPI server (just for example, sorry for replacing my domain with fake domain, as the project cannot be public at this moment):
https://railsapi.myprojectdomain.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBTQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--d9d49c5e9214e7b6ceb3247d30d8056dc1b1a1f9/015_cost%20an%20arm%20and%20a%20leg_BrightSide.jpg

Sometimes it works:
[image]

Sometimes it just doesn't work! (404):
[image]

Here is the related code as reference.

Model:

```
class IdiomOfTheDay < ApplicationRecord

has_one_attached :iotd_image

def image_url
    if self.iotd_image.attached?
        Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(self.iotd_image, only_path: true)
    else
        nil
    end
end
```

end

Controller is just used to create and render index to send the image url as json.

index.json.jbuilder:

```
json.data do
    json.idiom_of_the_day do   
        json.image_url idiom_of_the_day.image_url
    end
end
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
# Store files locally.
  config.active_storage.service = :local
  config.active_storage.service_urls_expire_in = 5.days
```

Adding a point of it, I have never suffered from this when I run the docker-compose locally. It only happens on the EC.

Thanks for reading my question. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked!

In `application_controller.rb` add the following

```
before_action do
   ActiveStorage::Current.host = API_URL //(http://localhost:3000)
end
```

And then in you model modify this

```
def image_url   
  if self.iotd_image.attached?
    self.iotd_image.url
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

It gives you the disk URL rather than the redirect URL